# How can I more succinctly fill in missing values in time series data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time-series

I have posted the code here:  https://gist.github.com/3102527

This code takes an array of sorted objects, where the date key is 'sent_hour' of the format "00"-"23. Some sent_hours are missing.  My code fills them in.

It is many lines. How can this be done in javascript in a few simple lines?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code (some or all) from your link. Links break over time and your question will be useful to other people longer if it contains code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function fillBlanks(ourHours, rawData) {
    ourHours = []; //init array
    for (var i=0; i<=23; i++) //fill array
        ourHours.push({"sent_hour": makeHourRange(i), "total": 0});

    for (h in rawData) //add data to array
        ourHours[rawData[h].sent_hour*1].total += rawData[h].total;

    return ourHours;
}

function makeHourRange(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num.toString() : num.toString();
}
```