# Fill in missing data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
 [
     {
         "time":  1,
         "value": 405.56
     },

     {
         "time":  2,
         "value": 407.64
     },

     {
         "time":  4,
         "value": 403.26
     },


     {
         "time":  5,
         "value": 403.26
     }
]
```

However, there are no objects at some time (eg `3` is missing in the above example).

For setting the value of this missing data to a default value, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463830/how-can-i-more-succinctly-fill-in-missing-values-in-time-series-data-in-javascri). However, what I want to do is *back-fill* the data. For example, I want to create a `3` object so it has the value of the previous object (407.64).

Is there a Javascript library available for doing this kind of manipulation? I do not want to code it myself as far as possible.

**EDIT**: There might be more missing values but the identifiers (`time`) will always be numeric.

Comment: Coding it yourself will probably make you gain time, experience and filesize. And this is a very specific need, it probably does not exists.

Comment: I dont think there is a library for this. This is a very specific requirement. Since its an array of objects, by getting the index of 2, you can populate a new object 3 with value of 2.

Comment: If you are sure that you have only numeric identifier you can do a for loop and check if the corresponding property exists in your array using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty. If it does not, you have to insert the previous value.

Comment: There might be multiple elements missing but the identifiers will always be numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwNEr/1/)

```
var test = [
     {
         "time":  1,
         "value": 405.56
     },

     {
         "time":  2,
         "value": 407.64
     },

     {
         "time":  7,
         "value": 403.26
     },


     {
         "time":  12,
         "value": 403.26
     }
]

function fill() {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = test.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (test[i]["time"] == test[i+1]["time"] - 1) {
            tmp.push(test[i]);
        } else {
            for (var j = test[i]["time"], l = test[i+1]["time"]; j < l; j++) {
                tmp.push(test[i]);
            };
        }
    };
    return tmp;
};

function printArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + i  + ": " + JSON.stringify(arr[i]) + "</p>";
    }
};

printArray(fill(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want with javascript code then try this-

```
function fillArray(arr){
var i=1;
while(i<arr.length){
  if((arr[i]["time"]*1-arr[i-1]["time"]*1) > 1){
    arr.splice(i,0,{"time":i+1, "value": arr[i-1]["value"]});

        }
  i++;
}
//console.log(arr);
return arr;
}
```